# 8000 updates per second using mysql

Tags: mysql

i'm using a 16 core machine with 48GB RAM and i have this data feed where its pumping out about 8000 elements that i need so about 8000 queries per second.  mysql is struggling pretty hard on it.  the table is in MEMORY not on disk (i'm trying what i can to make it fast and the table gets cleared everyday anyway) and i was wondering if there is a magic my.cnf i could be trying to speed this thing up.  its trying to do the inserts and then updates a lot, the reads are very little.

here is what i have.  go ahead and tell me how wrong it is.

```
skip-name-resolve
thread_cache_size = 128
table_cache = 4096
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 10M
read_buffer_size = 10M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 10M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
tmp_table_size=256M
query_cache_size=256M
query_cache_type=1
open_files_limit=8192
thread_concurrency=4

#used for tables in memory
max_heap_table_size=4000M

log_slow_queries=/var/log/mysql2/mysqld2.slow.log
long_query_time=2
```

a query could be like this:

```
UPDATE `pos` SET 
  `ExtID`='16044',
  `ECNID`='2814858', 
  `Pos`='-100', 
  `LAcct`='-100', 
  `SAcct`='0', 
  `CBasis`='-3515.00', 
  `EPrice`='359.15', 
  `OR`='XYZ', 
  `UID`='123', 
  `Rte`='AR', 
  `XYZRoute`='AR', 
  `PID`='AR', 
  `Time`='09:27:29', 
  `LXYZ`='R: Remove', 
  `LF`='-0.55', 
  `PF`='-0.00', 
  `TF`='-0.73', 
  `OF`='-0.00', 
  `SF`='-0.6896', 
  `CF`='-0.03', 
  `FF`='-0.0075', 
  `OF`='-0.0000', 
  `V`='AR', 
  `ECID`='AR', 
  `PO`='Y', 
  `Sold`='3515.00', 
  `SSold`='100', 
  `OC`='E', 
  `EA`='OV', 
  `S`='AREWAPL', 
  `U`='AESAPL', 
  `A`='12345', 
  `XXXID`='123471' 
WHERE `XXXID` = '1071' AND `EID` = '1' LIMIT 1
```

indexes are on XXXID and EID

Comment: update mean update or inserting?

Comment: Including your query and the table structure would go a long way to answering this.

Comment: the queries are basically not the same, they are dynamically built based on what data comes in.

Comment: i edited my question to show a sample query.  it tries to do an update first, if that fails then it knows the data isn't there so it does the insert on it.  next time it will exist and the update will happen

Comment: Are you using a statement that is prepared once, and reusing it by providing values from host variables?  Don't know if mysql supports this but I would imagine so.   This approach could make a big diff.

Comment: Most mysql installs come with 3 sample .ini files for small/medium/large setups. Have you tried the "large" one?

Comment: What is your programming language?  Connection per statement, multiple connections in a statement?  The compound values insert syntax?  Do you need immediate read?

Comment: i'm using perl, socket, while recv...update/insert.  so its trying to update/insert in the recv loop.  the perl in updating/inserting as fast as it can and then i have a php page with some ajax updating this view based on the updates every second.  mysql just can't keep up with the data and it starts lagging big time.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use a prepared statement with host variables.
2. Run multiple threads (otherwise 15 or your 16 cores are largely unused.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got a lot of memory, you might consider simply storing the incoming data points in memory (not mysql, just in an array using whatever programming language you're using). Periodically (say once an hour or something), spin off a new thread to bulk load the current memory dataset into your mysql database.

If you expect to be able to *query* this dataset in real time through mysql as it's being loaded, then you have a somewhat more complicated problem.

Comment: yes, mysql can't keep up with this feed.  i just assumed someone out there was doing something like this with this amount of data doing inserts with mysql