# Your suggestion to insert thousands of rows per second

Tags: mysql

I have a quiz web app.
I need to insert 300 rows per second for every student in the last moment of quiz. when quiz is finished I should insert thousands of records in my tables.
what is your suggestion for a issue like this.
I think I should use MyISAM, but I'm sure there are lot to do (query caching, replication, etc).
I want to know your suggestion...
thanks in advance.

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961189/8000-updates-per-second-using-mysql

Comment: actually it was not helpful for me...

Comment: What you need to insert? numbers? large BLOBs? more information.

Comment: bleow in @Clyndric I addressed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,140542,140542

or

http://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/entry/comparing_innodb_to_myisam_performance

The oracle guys are claiming: "Compared to MyISAM, InnoDB delivered 35x higher throughput on the Read / Write test"

Have a look at:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/01/08/innodb-vs-myisam-vs-falcon-benchmarks-part-1/

and to other articles from mysqlperformanceblog.com

Answer (score 0):

You don't give nearly enough information to give any sort of meaningful result.

Inserting a few thousand rows is usually nothing.  But I don't know if your rows contain 300 fields of BLOB data or whatever.

Google Premature Optimisation.

You start planning for a replication scenario now, and it could cost you a lot of time and money, not to mention long-term complexity, when it is most likely not necessary.

Have you tested it?  Create a dummy script that inserts as many records as you are expecting.

Comment: My answers table consists at most four fields: 1-questionID 2-answerID 3-userID and no more... Is it enough?